# c++ creating my own toString() method in header file

Tags: c++, templates, tostring

I am trying to override toString method like it is possible in Java. I am really new to C++, so even though test program using this header file will compile, it could have a lot of mistakes. My goal is to get the point back as string in the form of "(x1, x2, x3....x4)". The amount of coordinates will be changeing from 0 to n. How can I change toString() so that it would not return "test" but would return the coordinates of the point as String?

```
#ifndef POINT_H
#define POINT_H
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

#include <cmath>
using std::ostream;
using std::list;
using ::std::sqrt;
using namespace std;

template<unsigned short n>
class Point {

public:
    list <float> coords;
    Point <n>() = default; 
    Point <n>(list<float> coords){
        if (coords.size()!=n) {
            throw string ("Vale kordinaatide arv");
        }
        this-> coords=coords;
        }

        string toString() const {
        return "Test toString";
        }

        float distanceFrom (Point <n> v){
            float s=0;
            list<float> coords;
            auto it1= coords.begin();
            auto it2= v.coords.begin();
            while ((it1) != coords.end()){  
                s+=(*it1 -*it2)*(*it1-*it2);
                it1++;
                it2++;
            }
        return sqrt(s);
        }
    friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, const Point<n>& v)
    {
        out << "("<<"Test"<<")";
        return out;
    }
};


#endif
```

Comment: Hm, what exactly is your question? And EW, please don't put `using` declarations inside a header. Users of it will hate you.

Comment: If you don't know how to use it C++ (as is evidenced), starts by smaller pieces and only add to it after it compiles and runs as expected.

Comment: How can I change toString() so that it would not return "test" but would return the coordinates of the point as String.

Comment: user3328230 google "c++ strings" and read everything you can.

Comment: Can someone give me a more concrete answer what I am trying to do so wrong? Why cant it be done like that?

Comment: Why don't you just iterate over your list and put them in your stream? What is it that you can't do? And there is no `toString()` in C++ by default. If you want it, you have to make it.